# how to delete a row from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The data is getting propagated into my gridview. But, i am messing it up when i need to delete the data.

I have a delete button within my gridview as template field.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>
                                          <asp:Button ID="btnDelete"  runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Inventory SN?');" />
                                      </ItemTemplate>
                                  </asp:TemplateField>
```

And on the click event i have

```
 protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
            if (row != null)
            { 
            //what shall i write next??
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The data which is getting populated is not coming from one table. So, i just need to make it vanish.

Any kind of help will be gracefully accepted.

Comment: why don't you hide it in js or css?

Comment: i need to do it on gridview event or button click

Comment: how should he know which data delete?

Comment: Delete button is there for every entry

On the delete button click

Answer (score 0):

Why not deleting your selected row?

When you click your Delete button you also select the row.

Just call `yourgridview.SelectedItem` to get it.
Use `yourgridview.Remove(yourgridview.SelectedItem);` to remove it

```
if (dataGrid.SelectedItem != null)
{
    dataGrid.Items.Remove(dataGrid.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: Now I have @Arka